# Testing Ruby on Rails OAuth API from Ruby console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, oauth, console

I have Ruby on Rails application. Curently I'm trying to implement an OAuth API. Is there some way to test this API from Ruby console? In particular I need to do some POST requests to the API.

Basically I need to pretend as a client app from Ruby console, get access token and then call for API methods. Is there some tutorial or article on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Tests should be run from your test suite, not the console.

Comment: Well the API is not done yet. I'm still developing it.

Comment: You should be writing your tests first, not the API first.

Comment: Any hint or tutorial on how to write tests for OAuth based API? My point is I have no clue how to achive this :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test the complete OAuth flow and API access, you can use the [OAuth2 gem](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2).

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty much it. I just had to read documentation on OAuth gem. Turned out they had the example that (almost) worked from the Ruby console: http://rubydoc.info/github/oauth/oauth-ruby/master/file/README.rdoc

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [rest-client gem](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client). Besides the Ruby console, you might want to write a small ruby script using rest-client to automate your manual tests.

Comment: Looks interesting, will try it. Thanks!